# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'MicrossDashboard.DB.Customer'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am quite new to MVC and am therefore having trouble populating a DropDown list with data from a table in my DBContext. I have the following setup:

Within my Controller I have the following ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DBContext db = new DBContext();

    return View(db.Customers);

}
```

Then I am making my view Strongly Typed:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MicrossDashboard.DB.Customer>
```

And then in the same view I am trying to bind this to the Drop Down List:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Customer" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <span hidden id="customerValue">@customer.ToString()</span>
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ddlCustomer").DataTextField("CustomerName").DataValueField("pk_Customer_ID").BindTo(Model))
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am pretty sure that is it. When I try running the page I get the following error:

**A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'MicrossDashboard.DB.Customer'.**

Am I missing anything glaringly obvious?

Comment: Show the class definition for the type specified in the error message.  According to the message there is a property within that class which references the class itself.  So when you try to serialize an instance of that class you would end up with an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'MicrossDashboard.DB.Customer'.

That class is referencing itself in one of its properties.  As a simplified example, consider this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public MyClass Inner { get { return this; } }
}
```

If you were to try to serialize this, let's say to JSON, you'd end up with:

```
{
  "myInt" : 0,
  "inner" : {
    "myInt" : 0,
    "inner" : {
      "myInt" : 0,
      "inner" {
        // and so on, infinitely
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So no instance of that class could be serialized, because it would result in an infinite amount of data (not to mention an overflowed stack).

Your example might not be *that* obvious, but the problem still exists somewhere in your `MicrossDashboard.DB.Customer` class.  Somewhere within its properties, possibly multiple levels deep, an instance of that class references itself.

There are a variety of ways to "ignore" a field for serialization.  Options include [the `JsonIgnore` attribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonignoreattribute.htm), [the `ScriptIgnore` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute), omitting [the `DataMember` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx), etc.  It depends on how you perform your serialization.

Comment: Thanks David. So I am guessing there is nothing obvious from the code I have posted? The Class 'MicrossDashboard.DB.Customer' is generated by Entity Framework I believe (or Linq to SQL - I think its the former) - and is way over 2000 lines. Is it normal for this auto-generated code to cause this kind of error or could it be due to something else in the configuration do you think? I appreciate & take your points above, they make total sense but im still not exactly sure where to go from here.

Comment: @CJH: The generated code could easily include navigation properties which result in a circular reference.  For example, if this record has child records which in turn have "parent" navigation properties on those objects.  EF would know the difference, but the serializer wouldn't.  I haven't actually had to solve this before (I tend to avoid generated code), but something like this seems helpful: http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/  Essentially your goal is to get the serializer to ignore (or better handle) navigation properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that David! I will have a good read through that. As a total novice in this area, I am curious to know when/where the serialization is happening? I havent used JSON anywhere...?!